# run job script with different variables found in other files

Tags: bash, slurm, hpc

Let's suppose I have the following list of variables in a txt file (var.txt):

```
AAA
ABC
BBB
CCC
```

the following R script (script.R), where x is one variable in var.txt:

```
print(x)
```

and the following HPC slurm job script (job.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name test
#SBATCH --ntasks 8
#SBATCH --time 04:00
#SBATCH --output out
#SBATCH --error err

Rscript script.R
```

How can I run the job.sh script 4 times in sequence, each time with a different variable inside script.R?

Expected output:
4 slurm jobs with script.R printing AAA, ABC, BBB, and CCC.

Comment: I don't know R, but assuming it allows you to pass in a parameter on the command line, something like `while read -r var; do Rscript script.R --variable="$var"; done <var.txt` or somewhat more succinctly `xargs -i -n 1 Rscript script.R --variable={} <var.txt`

Comment: thanks, I think this answers half of the question. the last thing is that I need to launch 4 job.sh, each one with a different var

Comment: So you don't want them in sequence after all? Not too familiiar with `slurm` either but you can create four separate temporary files, or probably more ideally have it read your submissions from standard input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the typical workload suited for a [job array](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html). With a submission script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name test
#SBATCH --ntasks 8
#SBATCH --time 04:00
#SBATCH --output out
#SBATCH --error err
#SBATCH --array=0-3

readarray -t VARS < var.txt
VAR=${VARS[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}
export VAR

Rscript script.R
```

and `script.R` being

```
print(Sys.getenv("VAR"))
```

you will get a four-jobs job array, each one running the R script with a different value of the env var `VAR`, taken from the `var.txt` file.

Comment: thanks, it seems the right approach. I am trying to run this with my real script but it does not work. In my real case the "VAR" is inside an R function as follows: r_function(input.files= paste("beginning_file_", Sys.getenv("VAR"), "_end_file.nc", sep="")). but this does not work. any suggestion?

Comment: Difficult for me unless you make "not work" more explicit. Are you facing an error message? If so what does it say?

Comment: if I run your suggestion above I get the following output (from the last run for example):  "CCC\n" . so somehow it doesn't seem that var.txt has been read correctly, because when I print the VAR I get "\n" attached to VAR :(

Comment: Can you try this new version (with `-t`)